# mysql left join and search

Tags: mysql, left-join, where-clause

I have the following data set: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f4751/3

Simply I need to get court which `law_court_mesul_shexs`.`cif` is 008003 and 516561

```
SELECT 
    distinct `law_court_mesul_shexs`.`court_id`, 
    `law_court`.* 
FROM `law_court` 
LEFT JOIN `law_court_mesul_shexs` 
    ON `law_court`.`court_id` = `law_court_mesul_shexs`.`court_id` 
WHERE `law_court_mesul_shexs`.`cif` = '008003' 
    OR `law_court_mesul_shexs`.`cif`= '516561'
```

This sql works but it also returns court id 114 because 114 also have a CIF 008003.

But I want to get only court id 113, because I need to get courts which only CIF is 008003 and 516561.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use following approaches to get your desired result set

```
SELECT `c`.* 
FROM `law_court` c
JOIN (SELECT court_id
     FROM law_court_mesul_shexs
     WHERE cif IN('008003' , '516561')
     GROUP BY court_id
     HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT mesul_shexs_id) = 2
     ) s
ON `c`.`court_id` = `s`.`court_id`;
```

Or

```
SELECT `c`.* 
FROM `law_court` c
JOIN (SELECT court_id
     FROM law_court_mesul_shexs
     WHERE cif IN('008003' , '516561')
     GROUP BY court_id
     HAVING SUM(cif ='008003') > 0
     AND SUM(cif ='516561') > 0
     ) s
ON `c`.`court_id` = `s`.`court_id`
```

Or using `exists`

```
SELECT `c`.* 
FROM `law_court` c
WHERE EXISTS (
      SELECT 1
      FROM  law_court_mesul_shexs
      WHERE cif = '008003' AND court_id = c.court_id
) AND (
      SELECT 1
      FROM  law_court_mesul_shexs
      WHERE cif = '516561' AND court_id = c.court_id
)
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f4751/11)